# macOS: Determine real size of icon returned from iconForFile method

Tags: macos, cocoa, icons, appkit

I'd like a way to tell whether a file's icon only provides a 32 x 32 image or if it has modern large icon sizes (512 x 512), so that I know which upscale method to use when enlarging.

I've found that many cross-platform apps still only provide 32 x 32 size Mac icons, which tend to look terrible when blown up to larger sizes, unless upscaled with a nearest neighbour method. On the other hand, modern large icons tend to look terrible when upscaled with nearest neighbour. In my QuickLook extension, I get icon images using `[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] iconForFile:path]` which always returns an NSImage of size 32 x 32, but provides no clue to what the actual largest icon size available is.

If I iterate through its image representations, the largest one is always 2048 x 2048 pixels.

Is there a way to find out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check image representations. If it's `NSPDFImageRep` you can just call `[image setSize:NSMakeSize(512,512)];`

The easiest solution to get largest bitmap representation:

```
NSImageRep *imgRep = [image bestRepresentationForRect:NSMakeRect(0, 0, 2048, 2048) context:nil hints:nil];
NSLog(@"%@",NSStringFromSize([imgRep size]));
```

Alternatively check all given bitmap representations.

```
NSURL *URL;
CFErrorRef error;
URL = (__bridge_transfer NSURL *)LSCopyDefaultApplicationURLForContentType(kUTTypeVCard, kLSRolesViewer, &error);
NSImage *image = [[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] iconForFile:[URL path]];
NSArray<NSImageRep *>*representations = [image representations];
NSUInteger indexOfLargest = 0;
NSUInteger surfaceArea = 0;
for (NSUInteger i = 0 ; i < [representations count]; i++) {
    NSImageRep *rep = representations[i];
    if ([rep size].width * [rep size].height >= surfaceArea) {
        surfaceArea = [rep size].width * [rep size].height;
        indexOfLargest = i;
    }
}
NSLog(@"Representations %@", representations);
NSLog(@"Largest index is: %lu", (unsigned long)indexOfLargest);
```

Console output:

```
2021-07-16 19:02:07.816423+0200 testImages[13756:755791] Representations (
    "NSISIconImageRep 0x600002abe2b0 Size={32, 32} ColorSpace=Generic RGB colorspace BPS=0 Pixels=32x32 Alpha=NO AppearanceName=NSAppearanceNameAqua",
    "NSISIconImageRep 0x600002abe0d0 Size={32, 32} ColorSpace=Generic RGB colorspace BPS=0 Pixels=32x32 Alpha=NO AppearanceName=NSAppearanceNameDarkAqua",
    "NSISIconImageRep 0x600002abe1c0 Size={32, 32} ColorSpace=Generic RGB colorspace BPS=0 Pixels=64x64 Alpha=NO AppearanceName=NSAppearanceNameAqua",
    "NSISIconImageRep 0x600002abe3a0 Size={32, 32} ColorSpace=Generic RGB colorspace BPS=0 Pixels=64x64 Alpha=NO AppearanceName=NSAppearanceNameDarkAqua",
    "NSISIconImageRep 0x600002abe3f0 Size={16, 16} ColorSpace=Generic RGB colorspace BPS=0 Pixels=16x16 Alpha=NO AppearanceName=NSAppearanceNameAqua",
    "NSISIconImageRep 0x600002abe440 Size={16, 16} ColorSpace=Generic RGB colorspace BPS=0 Pixels=16x16 Alpha=NO AppearanceName=NSAppearanceNameDarkAqua",
    "NSISIconImageRep 0x600002abe490 Size={16, 16} ColorSpace=Generic RGB colorspace BPS=0 Pixels=32x32 Alpha=NO AppearanceName=NSAppearanceNameAqua",
    "NSISIconImageRep 0x600002abe530 Size={16, 16} ColorSpace=Generic RGB colorspace BPS=0 Pixels=32x32 Alpha=NO AppearanceName=NSAppearanceNameDarkAqua",
    "NSISIconImageRep 0x600002abe580 Size={18, 18} ColorSpace=Generic RGB colorspace BPS=0 Pixels=18x18 Alpha=NO AppearanceName=NSAppearanceNameAqua",
    "NSISIconImageRep 0x600002abe5d0 Size={18, 18} ColorSpace=Generic RGB colorspace BPS=0 Pixels=18x18 Alpha=NO AppearanceName=NSAppearanceNameDarkAqua",
    "NSISIconImageRep 0x600002abe620 Size={18, 18} ColorSpace=Generic RGB colorspace BPS=0 Pixels=36x36 Alpha=NO AppearanceName=NSAppearanceNameAqua",
    "NSISIconImageRep 0x600002abe4e0 Size={18, 18} ColorSpace=Generic RGB colorspace BPS=0 Pixels=36x36 Alpha=NO AppearanceName=NSAppearanceNameDarkAqua",
    "NSISIconImageRep 0x600002abe670 Size={24, 24} ColorSpace=Generic RGB colorspace BPS=0 Pixels=24x24 Alpha=NO AppearanceName=NSAppearanceNameAqua",
    "NSISIconImageRep 0x600002abe6c0 Size={24, 24} ColorSpace=Generic RGB colorspace BPS=0 Pixels=24x24 Alpha=NO AppearanceName=NSAppearanceNameDarkAqua",
    "NSISIconImageRep 0x600002abe710 Size={24, 24} ColorSpace=Generic RGB colorspace BPS=0 Pixels=48x48 Alpha=NO AppearanceName=NSAppearanceNameAqua",
    "NSISIconImageRep 0x600002abe760 Size={24, 24} ColorSpace=Generic RGB colorspace BPS=0 Pixels=48x48 Alpha=NO AppearanceName=NSAppearanceNameDarkAqua",
    "NSISIconImageRep 0x600002abe7b0 Size={128, 128} ColorSpace=Generic RGB colorspace BPS=0 Pixels=128x128 Alpha=NO AppearanceName=NSAppearanceNameAqua",
    "NSISIconImageRep 0x600002abe800 Size={128, 128} ColorSpace=Generic RGB colorspace BPS=0 Pixels=128x128 Alpha=NO AppearanceName=NSAppearanceNameDarkAqua",
    "NSISIconImageRep 0x600002abe850 Size={128, 128} ColorSpace=Generic RGB colorspace BPS=0 Pixels=256x256 Alpha=NO AppearanceName=NSAppearanceNameAqua",
    "NSISIconImageRep 0x600002abe8a0 Size={128, 128} ColorSpace=Generic RGB colorspace BPS=0 Pixels=256x256 Alpha=NO AppearanceName=NSAppearanceNameDarkAqua",
    "NSISIconImageRep 0x600002abe8f0 Size={256, 256} ColorSpace=Generic RGB colorspace BPS=0 Pixels=256x256 Alpha=NO AppearanceName=NSAppearanceNameAqua",
    "NSISIconImageRep 0x600002abe940 Size={256, 256} ColorSpace=Generic RGB colorspace BPS=0 Pixels=256x256 Alpha=NO AppearanceName=NSAppearanceNameDarkAqua",
    "NSISIconImageRep 0x600002abe990 Size={256, 256} ColorSpace=Generic RGB colorspace BPS=0 Pixels=512x512 Alpha=NO AppearanceName=NSAppearanceNameAqua",
    "NSISIconImageRep 0x600002abe9e0 Size={256, 256} ColorSpace=Generic RGB colorspace BPS=0 Pixels=512x512 Alpha=NO AppearanceName=NSAppearanceNameDarkAqua",
    "NSISIconImageRep 0x600002abea30 Size={512, 512} ColorSpace=Generic RGB colorspace BPS=0 Pixels=512x512 Alpha=NO AppearanceName=NSAppearanceNameAqua",
    "NSISIconImageRep 0x600002abea80 Size={512, 512} ColorSpace=Generic RGB colorspace BPS=0 Pixels=512x512 Alpha=NO AppearanceName=NSAppearanceNameDarkAqua",
    "NSISIconImageRep 0x600002abead0 Size={512, 512} ColorSpace=Generic RGB colorspace BPS=0 Pixels=1024x1024 Alpha=NO AppearanceName=NSAppearanceNameAqua",
    "NSISIconImageRep 0x600002abeb20 Size={512, 512} ColorSpace=Generic RGB colorspace BPS=0 Pixels=1024x1024 Alpha=NO AppearanceName=NSAppearanceNameDarkAqua",
    "NSISIconImageRep 0x600002abeb70 Size={1024, 1024} ColorSpace=Generic RGB colorspace BPS=0 Pixels=1024x1024 Alpha=NO AppearanceName=NSAppearanceNameAqua",
    "NSISIconImageRep 0x600002abebc0 Size={1024, 1024} ColorSpace=Generic RGB colorspace BPS=0 Pixels=1024x1024 Alpha=NO AppearanceName=NSAppearanceNameDarkAqua",
    "NSISIconImageRep 0x600002abec10 Size={1024, 1024} ColorSpace=Generic RGB colorspace BPS=0 Pixels=2048x2048 Alpha=NO AppearanceName=NSAppearanceNameAqua",
    "NSISIconImageRep 0x600002abec60 Size={1024, 1024} ColorSpace=Generic RGB colorspace BPS=0 Pixels=2048x2048 Alpha=NO AppearanceName=NSAppearanceNameDarkAqua"
)
2021-07-16 19:02:07.854533+0200 testImages[13756:755791] Largest index is: 31
```

If you want to have access to original icon representations:

```
    NSImage *image = nil;
    OSErr err;
    
    err = GetIconRefFromTypeInfo(0, 0, CFSTR("pdf"), 0, 0, &iconRef);
    if (err == noErr && iconRef) {
        
        IconFamilyHandle iconFamily = NULL;
        err = IconRefToIconFamily(iconRef, kSelectorAllAvailableData, &iconFamily);
        ReleaseIconRef(iconRef);

        if(err == noErr && iconFamily)
        {
            NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytes:*iconFamily length:GetHandleSize((Handle)iconFamily)];
            image = [[NSImage alloc] initWithData:data];
        }
    }
```

Console:

```
2021-07-19 13:35:33.716142+0200 testImages2[10434:559291] Representations (
    "NSBitmapImageRep 0x60000016e8b0 Size={512, 512} ColorSpace=(not yet loaded) BPS=8 BPP=(not yet loaded) Pixels=1024x1024 Alpha=YES Planar=NO Format=(not yet loaded) CurrentBacking=nil (faulting) CGImageSource=0x600002a3eca0",
    "NSBitmapImageRep 0x60000014bc60 Size={256, 256} ColorSpace=(not yet loaded) BPS=8 BPP=(not yet loaded) Pixels=512x512 Alpha=YES Planar=NO Format=(not yet loaded) CurrentBacking=nil (faulting) CGImageSource=0x600002a3eca0",
    "NSBitmapImageRep 0x60000014bdb0 Size={512, 512} ColorSpace=(not yet loaded) BPS=8 BPP=(not yet loaded) Pixels=512x512 Alpha=YES Planar=NO Format=(not yet loaded) CurrentBacking=nil (faulting) CGImageSource=0x600002a3eca0",
    "NSBitmapImageRep 0x60000014bf00 Size={128, 128} ColorSpace=(not yet loaded) BPS=8 BPP=(not yet loaded) Pixels=256x256 Alpha=YES Planar=NO Format=(not yet loaded) CurrentBacking=nil (faulting) CGImageSource=0x600002a3eca0",
    "NSBitmapImageRep 0x60000014ca10 Size={256, 256} ColorSpace=(not yet loaded) BPS=8 BPP=(not yet loaded) Pixels=256x256 Alpha=YES Planar=NO Format=(not yet loaded) CurrentBacking=nil (faulting) CGImageSource=0x600002a3eca0",
    "NSBitmapImageRep 0x600000144000 Size={128, 128} ColorSpace=(not yet loaded) BPS=8 BPP=(not yet loaded) Pixels=128x128 Alpha=YES Planar=NO Format=(not yet loaded) CurrentBacking=nil (faulting) CGImageSource=0x600002a3eca0",
    "NSBitmapImageRep 0x6000001441c0 Size={32, 32} ColorSpace=(not yet loaded) BPS=8 BPP=(not yet loaded) Pixels=64x64 Alpha=YES Planar=NO Format=(not yet loaded) CurrentBacking=nil (faulting) CGImageSource=0x600002a3eca0",
    "NSBitmapImageRep 0x600000144310 Size={16, 16} ColorSpace=(not yet loaded) BPS=8 BPP=(not yet loaded) Pixels=32x32 Alpha=YES Planar=NO Format=(not yet loaded) CurrentBacking=nil (faulting) CGImageSource=0x600002a3eca0",
    "NSBitmapImageRep 0x6000001443f0 Size={32, 32} ColorSpace=(not yet loaded) BPS=8 BPP=(not yet loaded) Pixels=32x32 Alpha=YES Planar=NO Format=(not yet loaded) CurrentBacking=nil (faulting) CGImageSource=0x600002a3eca0",
    "NSBitmapImageRep 0x6000001444d0 Size={16, 16} ColorSpace=(not yet loaded) BPS=8 BPP=(not yet loaded) Pixels=16x16 Alpha=YES Planar=NO Format=(not yet loaded) CurrentBacking=nil (faulting) CGImageSource=0x600002a3eca0"
)
```

Comment: Well, that's what I was doing, and apparently the  largest image representation for the icons I've checked is 2048 x 2048 although the actual icon image used to build the application is only 32 x 32. I guess this means that the 2048 x 2048 ugly blown-up version has already been created somewhere else, whenever macOS creates its icon images, and the system has no way of telling that this is not the original  icon size.

Comment: Just use something like this NSImageRep *imgRep = [image bestRepresentationForRect:NSMakeRect(0, 0, 512, 512) context:nil hints:nil];
    NSLog(@"%@",NSStringFromSize([imgRep size])); It's either you know what size you want or you want the largest.

Comment: The thing is, I don't know beforehand what size I want. This is for a QuickLook plugin that will show icons from many different application. Some of them are full sized 2048 x 2048, others are 32 x 32, and I'd like a way to determine which is which.

Comment: Do you have example when it's the icon blown up (upscaled 32)?

Comment: Here is an example. This is a TADS 3 game file that gets its icon from Gargoyle: https://ibb.co/p1hKn4n

Comment: And here is a mockup of how I would like it to look instead: https://ibb.co/pd9gs3C

Comment: @PetterSjölund I updated answer. Those methods still work but are deprecated. If original icns file has only 16x16 - the last method will give only that icon and you can manually upscale with disabled antialiasing. If the file has upscaled icons -> dead end and you cannot do anything.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help! Unfortunately that last method gives me a blurry 512 x 512 icon, so I guess that is my answer. It would be interesting to know where or when the upscaling happens, but that is out of scope for this question. If you add some mention of the the fact that what I want to do can't be done in this case, I will mark it as an accepted answer.

Comment: @PetterSjölund If the original document icon file is blurry at 512x512 -> it was created during packaging with "iconutil" like that (Xcode uses it on background).  AppKit + NSISIconImageRep -> it's created using [NSImage initWithIconRef:] with "setScalesWhenResized:YES" in a loop with predetermined sizes. Yes they use these deprecated functions on Big Sur. You can look into it using hopperapp + drag&drop AppKit.framework onto it (on Big Sur it's more complicated)

Comment: I finally hacked around this by detecting the most common blurry icons and replacing them with sharper images I included in the bundle. I'll still mark the answer as the solution, as it is likely to be more useful to other people than my hack.